# Android studio 2.1.1: No maven option in "import project from external model"

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio

I'm trying to import maven project to android studio 2.1.1.
However, there is no "Maven" option in "import project from external model".
As shown in the figure bellow

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4CmY.jpg

while it should be like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM7xW.jpg

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/importing-project-from-maven-model.html

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie Thanks, but it is not helpful. in point (3) they said select "maven" but I dont have maven option

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the android studio and install to the latest version?

Or you just try to `Open Project`, don't use `import project from maven`

Comment: it is the latest version, open project doesn't work, it should be build using maven